# How do I transfer APT to an account that doesn't exist on-chain yet?

Tags: aptos

As I understand it, if you transfer APT to an account that doesn't exist on-chain yet, doing so will create the account on-chain. I've been trying to use `0x1::coin::transfer`, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
Move abort in 0x1::coin: ECOIN_STORE_NOT_PUBLISHED(0x60005): Account hasn't registered `CoinStore` for `CoinType`
```

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit confusing but there are two different functions.

- This one only transfers coins if the account already exists on-chain: `0x1::coin::transfer`. [Code](https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/blob/21991ffa96acde5ec211ba73dea42528a29b1e01/aptos-move/framework/aptos-framework/sources/coin.move#L434).
- This one will create the account first if it doesn't exist yet: `0x1::aptos_account::transfer`. [Code](https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/blob/21991ffa96acde5ec211ba73dea42528a29b1e01/aptos-move/framework/aptos-framework/sources/aptos_account.move#L25).

You can see in the second code link that it first checks if the account exists and creates it if it doesn't, and then calls `0x1::coin::transfer`.

Comment: As I can see, there is no method in Typescript SDK for `0x1::aptos_account::transfer`, isn't it? Are there any proposal to add it or should I implement it by myself just like creating and signing a transaction?

Comment: It's not implemented in the TS SDK currently, though I've opened an issue to add it: https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/issues/5720.

Comment: Okay done! I've added another answer that uses the TS SDK.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer, see this snippet demonstrating how to transfer coins with the TS SDK:

```js
import { AptosAccount, HexString } from "aptos";

const privateKeyHex =
  "0xdcaf65ead38f7cf0cb1f81961f8fc7f9b7f1e2f45e2d4a6da0dbef85f46f6054"; // fake private key of course
const privateKeyBytes = HexString.ensure(privateKeyHex).toUint8Array();
const myAccount = new AptosAccount(privateKeyBytes);

const txnHash = await coinClient.transfer(
  myAccount,
  "0x232098630cfad4734812fa37dc18d9b8d59242feabe49259e26318d468a99584",
  717,
  { createReceiverIfMissing: true }
);

await client.waitForTransaction(txnHash, { checkSuccess: true });
```

- If `createReceiverIfMissing` is false, it calls `0x1::coin::transfer`.
- If `createReceiverIfMissing` is true, it calls `0x1::aptos_account::transfer`.